# Array to Hash Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashmap

Convert this Array:

```
a = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"]
```

...to a Hash:

```
{ "item 1" => "item 2", "item 3" => "item 4" }
```

i.e. elements at *even* indexes are *keys* and *odd* ones are *values*.

Comment: Is there a comparisson of the performance of the different approaches? I commented a list of some ideas at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13017501/4575793)

Answer (score 372, accepted):

```
a = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"]
h = Hash[*a] # => { "item 1" => "item 2", "item 3" => "item 4" }
```

That's it. The `*` is called the *splat* operator.

One caveat per @Mike Lewis (in the comments): "Be very careful with this. Ruby expands splats on the stack. If you do this with a large dataset, expect to blow out your stack."

So, for most general use cases this method is great, but use a different method if you want to do the conversion on lots of data. For example, @Łukasz Niemier (also in the comments) offers this method for large data sets:

```
h = Hash[a.each_slice(2).to_a]
```

Comment: what does the `*` do in this example?

Comment: @tester, the `*` is called the *splat* operator. It takes an array and converts it a literal list of items. So `*[1,2,3,4]` => `1, 2, 3, 4`. In this example, the above is equivalent to doing `Hash["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"]`. And `Hash` has a `[]` method that accepts a list of arguments (making even indexes keys and odd indexes values), but `Hash[]` does not accept an array, so we splat the array using `*`.

Comment: @tester Another common use case for splat is to use in reverse, to define methods with unknown number of parameters. E.g `def whatever *args`. You can pass in a list like `whatever(7, 1, 3, 4)`. And as above, `*args` represents a list and `args` represents an array. Since you are passing in a list, you are actually passing in the `*args`. Thus `args` is an array, and what you end up with is `args == [7, 1, 3, 4]`. So you can pass in whatever parameters you want into the method and then just use `args` to access them.

Comment: Be very careful with this. Ruby expands splats on the stack. If you do this with a large dataset, expect to blow out your stack.

Comment: @MikeLewis, thanks for the caveat. I've added that to my answer (with attribution to you).

Comment: Another caveat, this method raises an exception if you pass in an array with an odd number of elements. `ArgumentError: odd number of arguments for Hash`

Comment: On big data tables you can use `Hash[a.each_slice(2).to_a]`.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier, thanks for that. I've edited that into my answer (with attribution to you)

Comment: @Kevin, the *stack* uses a small area of memory that the program allocates and reserves for certain specific operations. Most commonly, it is used to keep a stack of the methods that have been called so far. This is the origin of the term *stack trace*, and this is also why an infinitely recursive method can cause a *stack overflow*. The method in this answer also uses the stack, but since the stack is only a small area of memory, if you try this method with a large array, it will fill up the stack and cause an error (an error along the same lines as a stack overflow).

Comment: Now it is possible to do `a.each_slice(2).to_h` (at least in YARV).

Comment: Simple code sample to see the error when trying to send a huge number of arguments using splat: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1210854

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct anymore. The linked documentation at the start of the answer says that `to_h` operates on an array of arrays. Running `["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"].to_h` results in
`TypeError Exception: wrong element type String at 0 (expected array)`. `[["item 1", "item 2"], ["item 3", "item 4"]].to_h` works though. I think @hauleth is right, the correct answer in my testing with Ruby 2.5.3 is `a.each_slice(2).to_h`

Comment: Yup, doesn't seem to work anymore. Removed that answer. Left my original hash splat answer since that never stopped working, and was my original answer anyway.

Comment: Also the `each_slice(2).to_h` method i already had listed in my answer.

Answer (score 135):

Ruby 2.1.0 introduced a `to_h` method on Array that does what you require if your original array consists of arrays of key-value pairs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h.

```
[[:foo, :bar], [1, 2]].to_h
# => {:foo => :bar, 1 => 2}
```

Comment: for pre 2.1.0 ruby versions, you can use the Hash::[] method to get the similar results, as long as you have pairs of a nested array. so  a =[[:foo, :1], [bar, 2]] --- Hash[a] => {:foo=>1, :bar=>2}

Comment: @AfDev, indeed, thanks. You're correct (when ignoring the minor typos: `bar` needs to be a symbol, and the symbol `:2` should be an integer. So, your expression corrected is `a = [[:foo, 1], [:bar, 2]]`).

Answer (score 31):

Just use `Hash.[]` with the values in the array. For example:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]
Hash[*arr] #=> gives {1 => 2, 3 => 4}
```

Comment: @Marius: `*arr` converts `arr` into an argument list, so this is calling the `[]` method of Hash with the contents of arr as arguments.

Comment: Consider the remarks on the splat operator as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028362/4575793).

Answer (score 26):

Or if you have an array of `[key, value]` arrays, you can do:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].inject({}) do |r, s|
  r.merge!({s[0] => s[1]})
end # => { 1 => 2, 3 => 4 }
```

Comment: Nope. It would return `{ [1, 2] => [3, 4] }`. And since the question's title says "Array to Hash" and the built-in "Hash to Array" method does: `{ 1 => 2, 3 => 4}.to_a # => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]`, I thought more than one could end here trying to get the inverse of the built-in "Hash to Array" method. Actually, that's how I ended here anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I added a spare asterisk. `Hash[arr]` will do the job for you.

Comment: IMHO better solution: Hash[*array.flatten(1)]

Comment: Yossi: Sorry for raising the dead, but there is one bigger problem with his answer, and that is the use of `#inject` method. With `#merge!`, `#each_with_object` should have been used. If `#inject` is insisted upon, `#merge` rather than `#merge!` should have been used.

Comment: Now days you can do this short and sweet: `[[1, 2], [3, 4]].to_h`

Answer (score 17):

This is what I was looking for when googling this:

`[{a: 1}, {b: 2}].reduce({}) { |h, v| h.merge v }
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}`

Comment: You don't want to use `merge`, it constructs and discards a new hash per loop iteration and is very slow. If you've got a array of hashes try `[{a:1},{b:2}].reduce({}, :merge!)` instead - it merges everything into the same (new) hash.

Comment: You can also do `.reduce(&:merge!)`

Comment: `[{a: 1}, {b: 2}].reduce(&:merge!)` evaluates to `{:a=>1, :b=>2}`

Comment: This works because inject/reduce has a feature where you can omit the argument, in which case it uses the first argument of the array to operate on _as_ the input argument, and the rest of the array as the array. Combine that with symbol-to-proc and you get this concise construction. In other words `[{a: 1}, {b: 2}].reduce(&:merge!)` is the same as `[{a: 1}, {b: 2}].reduce { |m, x| m.merge(x) }` which is the same as `[{b: 2}].reduce({a: 1}) { |m, x| m.merge(x) }`.

Comment: two caveats: (1) this _mutates_ the original first element of the array in place. if you don't want to do that, you either have to explicitly pass in `{}`, or use non-mutating `merge` which has the same performance issue as described above; (2) the input array needs to have at least 1 element, otherwise you will get `nil` back instead of an empty hash

Comment: If you don't want to mutate the element in place, you should consider `each_with_object({})` (ruby >= 1.9.1.378) as in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017531/4575793) instead of inject/reduce.

Answer (score 10):

[`Enumerator`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerator.html) includes [`Enumerable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html). Since `2.1`, `Enumerable` also has a method [`#to_h`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h). That's why, we can write :-

```
a = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"]
a.each_slice(2).to_h
# => {"item 1"=>"item 2", "item 3"=>"item 4"}
```

Because [`#each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) without block gives us `Enumerator`, and as per the above explanation, we can call the `#to_h` method on the `Enumerator` object.

Answer (score 8):

You could try like this, for single array

```
irb(main):019:0> a = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"]
  => ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"]
irb(main):020:0> Hash[*a]
  => {"item 1"=>"item 2", "item 3"=>"item 4"}
```

for array of array

```
irb(main):022:0> a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
  => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
irb(main):023:0> Hash[*a.flatten]
  => {1=>2, 3=>4}
```

Comment: Consider the remarks on the splat operator as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028362/4575793).

Answer (score 7):

```
a = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"]
Hash[ a.each_slice( 2 ).map { |e| e } ]
```

or, if you hate `Hash[ ... ]`:

```
a.each_slice( 2 ).each_with_object Hash.new do |(k, v), h| h[k] = v end
```

or, if you are a lazy fan of broken functional programming:

```
h = a.lazy.each_slice( 2 ).tap { |a|
  break Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = a.find { |e, _| e == k }[1] }
}
#=> {}
h["item 1"] #=> "item 2"
h["item 3"] #=> "item 4"
```

Comment: If you don't fully hate `Hash[ ... ]` but want to use it as a chained method (like you can do with `to_h`) you can combine Boris suggestions and write: `arr.each_slice( 2 ).map { |e| e }.tap { |a| break Hash[a] }`

Comment: To make the semantics of the code above clearer: This will create **a "lazy hash" h**, which is initially **empty**, and will pull out elements from the original array a when needed. Only then will they actually be stored in h!

Comment: Don't do all of the suggestions here iterate multiple times through the whole array? This might be a downside.

Answer (score 2):

All answers assume the starting array is unique. OP did not specify how to handle arrays with duplicate entries, which result in duplicate keys.

Let's look at:

```rb
a = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 1", "item 5"]
```

You will lose the `item 1 => item 2` pair as it is overridden bij `item 1 => item 5`:

```rb
Hash[*a]
=> {"item 1"=>"item 5", "item 3"=>"item 4"}
```

All of the methods, including the `reduce(&:merge!)` result in the same removal.

It could be that this is exactly what you expect, though. But in other cases, you probably want to get a result with an `Array` for value instead:

```rb
{"item 1"=>["item 2", "item 5"], "item 3"=>["item 4"]}
```

The naïve way would be to create a helper variable, a hash that has a default value, and then fill that in a loop:

```rb
result = Hash.new {|hash, k| hash[k] = [] } # Hash.new with block defines unique defaults.
a.each_slice(2) {|k,v| result[k] << v }
a
=> {"item 1"=>["item 2", "item 5"], "item 3"=>["item 4"]}
```

It might be possible to use `assoc` and `reduce` to do above in one line, but that becomes much harder to reason about and read.

Comment: This seems like a predestined case to apply `each_with_object({})` (ruby >= 1.9.1.378) as in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017531/4575793).