# Is there a more efficient way to turn an array into a hash?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I think that my method is a little clumsy, and that there is likely to be a one-liner that I'm missing.  Ideas?

```
def _to_hash 
    hsh = {}
    self.each_slice(2){|v| hsh[v[0]] = v[1]}
    hsh
end

1.9.3-p0 :003 > ["a", 1, "b", 2]._to_hash
{
    "a" => 1,
    "b" => 2
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array to Hash Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028329/array-to-hash-ruby)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want Hash's .[] operator:

```
> Hash["a", 1, "b", 2]
 => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
```

Answer (score 4):

@phiggy's method is correct, but also remember that you can use a splat operator:

```
a = ["a", 1, "b", 2]
Hash[*a] #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
```