# Ruby - mapping an array to hashmap

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have an array, and a function that returns a value given a value. Ultimately I want to create a hashmap that has the values of the array as key value, and the result of f(key_value)  as the value. Is there a clean, simple way, like similar to each/map of Array, of doing this using block?

So something that is equivalent to

```
hsh = {}
[1,2,3,4].each do |x|
  hsh[x] = f(x)
end
```

but looks more similar to this, in that it's simple and one line?

```
results = array.map { | x | f(x) }
```

Comment: Can anybody say something about a comparison between the methods? We right now have [`.to_h` (ruby >= 2.6)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54023057/4575793), [`.map(...).to_h` (ruby >=2.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30887585/4575793) (both supporting lazy enumerators), [`Hash.new` (with lookup `f(...)`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017612/4575793), [`each_with_object({})` (ruby >= 1.9.1.378) and `Hash[...]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017531/4575793), [`index_with(&:...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017567/4575793)[rails >= 6](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/Enumerable/index_with).

Comment: So my follow-up question is how do these 6 different methods perform? I would expect 1 to be the best, followed by 3 or 6? 4 is also only iterating one-time through, but i remember `each_with_object` to be inferior. 2 and 5 should be slower as they iterate twice. Are my assumptions true? I know that this is also about memory, not only CPU bandwidth. Or is this a whole separate question? (Just for the the sake of completeness: [Hash[...]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017531/4575793) is [ruby >= v1.8.6.287](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_8_6_287/Hash)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could also define the function as the hash's default value:

```
hash = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = f(key) }
```

Then when you lookup a value, the hash will calculate and store it on the fly.

```
hash[10]
hash.inspect #=> { 10 => whatever_the_result_is }
```

Answer (score 148):

Note that since Ruby 2.1.0 you can also use [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h), like this:

```rb
[1,2,3,4].map{ |x| [x, f(x)] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 96):

Ruby 2.6.0 enables [passing a block to the `to_h`-method](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/2.6.html#to_h-with-a-block). This enables an even shorter syntax for creating a hash from an array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].to_h { |x| [x, f(x)] }
```

Comment: short and sweet

Answer (score 33):

You need `each_with_object`.

```
def f x
  x * 2
end

t = [1, 2, 3, 4].each_with_object({}) do |x, memo|
  memo[x] = f(x)
end

t # => {1=>2, 2=>4, 3=>6, 4=>8}
```

Another one:

```
t2 = [1, 2, 3, 4].map{|x| [x, f(x)]}
Hash[t2] # => {1=>2, 2=>4, 3=>6, 4=>8}
```

Comment: Just for the completeness (suggested edits are full): [this is Ruby >= 1.9.1.378](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_1_378/Enumerable/each_with_object).

Comment: @Cadoiz: I am quite sure no one is using a 14yo ruby version. It's not whisky :) But thanks, good note.

Answer (score 25):

Check out the [Hash::[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) method.

```
Hash[ [1,2,3,4].collect { |x| [x, f(x)] } ]
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work with lazy enumerators, but Ruby 2.1.0's `.to_h` does.

Answer (score 11):

From Ruby 2.1:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map { |x| [x, f(x)] }.to_h
```

[EDIT] Using Facets' [mash](https://web.archive.org/web/20210917073754/https://rdoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/master/Enumerable#mash-instance_method) (method to convert enumerable to hashes) (unmaintained?):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].mash { |x| [x, f(x)] }
```

Comment: @Cadoiz thx, updated. Not sure facets is being developed anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Also, Rails method [index_with](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/index_with) would be helpful:

```rb
a = ['a', 'bsdf', 'wqqwc']
a.index_with(&:size)
=> {"a"=>1, "bsdf"=>4, "wqqwc"=>5}
```

Comment: Turns out I misread the question, and I was actually looking for `index_by`, which does the opposite (function yields the keys; elements become the values).

Comment: You also do `index_with {...}` and give it a block and it is [rails >= 6.](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/Enumerable/index_with). This link also provides an example for that (unfortunately the sugessted edit queue is full).

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR: Comparing the different solutions in this Q/A

All tested options are fine. [`Hash.new` with a lookup function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017612/4575793) performs best. No declaration cost and still approximately as fast if you access every element once. As long as `f(...)` is cheap, as it's a lazy/on-demand data structure then. If you need your results right away, chose any other one that suits your needs and suffer at most ~16% penalty.

---

This answer tries to be a summery of the existing other ones to answer a follow-up question the reader might have: which is the best solution?
I will provide all the ressources to reproduce/verify my results and compare the existing answers, ordered by decreasing trend (at time of writing). Right now, even ruby2.6 is out-of support for more then a year, so we can probably assume that everything will be supported now. So let's start with this table for an overview:

| Method | Version (Docu link) | Lazy Enumerator Support |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [`.to_h`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54023057/4575793) | [ruby >= 2.6](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/2.6.html#to_h-with-a-block) | Yes |
| [`.map(...).to_h`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30887585/4575793) | [ruby >= 2.1](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) | Yes |
| [`Hash.new` (with lookup f(...))](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017612/4575793) | [ruby >= 1.8.6.287](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_8_6_287/Hash) | Different approach, is somewhat lazy |
| [each_with_object({})](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017531/4575793) | [ruby >= 1.9.1.378](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_1_378/Enumerable/each_with_object) | [No](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/lazy) |
| [Hash[...], index_with(&:...)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017531/4575793) | [rails >= 6](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/Enumerable/index_with) | [No](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017501/ruby-mapping-an-array-to-hashmap/13017567#comment83967355_13017567) |

There are more options such as [`Enumerable#reduce`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/reduce) + [`Hash#merge!`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge!) which are not scope of this answer. You can consider [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68745019/4575793) discussing it's advantages, I took some inspiration/structure from there.

So these are the different solutions I have compiled and benchmarked:

### Presenting the full solutions in code

```rb
a = [1,2,3,4]
def f key
  key
end

g = a.to_h { |x| [x, f(x)] }
k = a.map { |x| [x, f(x)] }.to_h
o = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = f(key) }
q = a.each_with_object({}) { |x, memo| memo[x] = f(x) }
s = a.index_with(&:c) # not tested
```

### Benchmark script

According to [noraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5511315/noraj), you should use [bmbm](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html#method-c-bmbm) and not `bm` to avoid differences due to the cost of memory allocation and garbage collection. This is an important point I'm discussing later in "Interpretation".

```rb
require 'benchmark'

a = (1..1_000_000)
b = a.to_a
def f key
  key
end

# Just for accessing later, not important
g = a.to_h { |x| [x, f(x)] }; h = b.to_h { |x| [x, f(x)] }; i = a.to_h { |x| [x, x] }; j = b.to_h { |x| [x, x] }; k = a.map { |x| [x, f(x)] }.to_h; l = b.map { |x| [x, f(x)] }.to_h; m = a.map { |x| [x, x] }.to_h; n = b.map { |x| [x, x] }.to_h; o = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = f(key) }; q = a.each_with_object({}) { |x, memo| memo[x] = f(x) }; r = b.each_with_object({}) { |x, memo| memo[x] = f(x) };


Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report('Declaration of a.to_h { function }:') { a.to_h { |x| [x, f(x)] } }
  x.report('Declaration of b.to_h { function }:') { b.to_h { |x| [x, f(x)] } }
  x.report('Declaration of a.to_h { array }:') { a.to_h { |x| [x, x] } }
  x.report('Declaration of b.to_h { array }:') { b.to_h { |x| [x, x] } }
  x.report('Declaration of a.map { function }.to_h:') { a.map { |x| [x, f(x)] }.to_h }
  x.report('Declaration of b.map { function }.to_h:') { b.map { |x| [x, f(x)] }.to_h }
  x.report('Declaration of a.map { array }.to_h:') { a.map { |x| [x, x] }.to_h }
  x.report('Declaration of b.map { array }.to_h:') { b.map { |x| [x, x] }.to_h }
  x.report('Declaration of Hash.new (with lookup)') { Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = c(key) } }
  x.report('Declaration of a.each_with_object({})') { a.each_with_object({}) { |x, memo| memo[x] = f(x) } }
  x.report('Declaration of a.each_with_object({})') { b.each_with_object({}) { |x, memo| memo[x] = f(x) } }

  x.report('Accessing from a.to_h { function }:') { a.reduce { |sum, x| g[x] } }
  x.report('Accessing from b.to_h { function }:') { a.reduce { |sum, x| h[x] } }
  x.report('Accessing from a.to_h { array }:') { a.reduce { |sum, x| i[x] } }
  x.report('Accessing from b.to_h { array }:') { a.reduce { |sum, x| j[x] } }
  x.report('Accessing from a.map { function }.to_h:') { a.reduce { |sum, x| k[x] } }
  x.report('Accessing from b.map { function }.to_h:') { a.reduce { |sum, x| l[x] } }
  x.report('Accessing from a.map { array }.to_h:') { a.reduce { |sum, x| m[x] } }
  x.report('Accessing from b.map { array }.to_h:') { a.reduce { |sum, x| n[x] } }
  x.report('Accessing from Hash.new (with lookup)') { a.reduce { |sum, x| o[x] } }
  x.report('Accessing from a.each_with_object({})') { a.reduce { |sum, x| q[x] } }
  x.report('Accessing from b.each_with_object({})') { a.reduce { |sum, x| r[x] } }
end
```

### Benchmark results for 5M items iterator/array

```
                                             user     system      total        real
Declaration of a.to_h { function }:       1.650822   0.091929   1.742751 (  1.742868)
Declaration of b.to_h { function }:       1.170426   0.071894   1.242320 (  1.242395)
Declaration of a.to_h { array }:          1.604802   0.051815   1.656617 (  1.660191)
Declaration of b.to_h { array }:          1.159055   0.007980   1.167035 (  1.167077)
Declaration of a.map { function }.to_h:   1.511910   0.099993   1.611903 (  1.611978)
Declaration of b.map { function }.to_h:   1.381991   0.112121   1.494112 (  1.494172)
Declaration of a.map { array }.to_h:      1.399749   0.091984   1.491733 (  1.491789)
Declaration of b.map { array }.to_h:      1.440968   0.039829   1.480797 (  1.480845)
Declaration of Hash.new (with lookup)     0.000017   0.000001   0.000018 (  0.000009)
Declaration of a.each_with_object({})     1.496914   0.131904   1.628818 (  1.628930)
Declaration of a.each_with_object({})     1.438418   0.180053   1.618471 (  1.618551)

Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Accessing from a.to_h { function }:       1.005993   0.000323   1.006316 (  1.006360)
Accessing from b.to_h { function }:       0.999888   0.000164   1.000052 (  1.000107)
Accessing from a.to_h { array }:          0.998487   0.000068   0.998555 (  0.998610)
Accessing from b.to_h { array }:          1.003892   0.000139   1.004031 (  1.004061)
Accessing from a.map { function }.to_h:   1.023635   0.000115   1.023750 (  1.023789)
Accessing from b.map { function }.to_h:   1.006790   0.000061   1.006851 (  1.006912)
Accessing from a.map { array }.to_h:      1.005898   0.000204   1.006102 (  1.006155)
Accessing from b.map { array }.to_h:      1.013491   0.000000   1.013491 (  1.013545)
Accessing from Hash.new (with lookup)     2.289310   0.139982   2.429292 (  2.429415)
Accessing from a.each_with_object({})     1.011719   0.000078   1.011797 (  1.011855)
Accessing from b.each_with_object({})     1.002672   0.000026   1.002698 (  1.002755)
----------------------------------------------------------------- total: 12.502935sec

                                              user     system      total        real
Accessing from a.to_h { function }:       1.006216   0.000003   1.006219 (  1.006290)
Accessing from b.to_h { function }:       1.006313   0.000003   1.006316 (  1.006342)
Accessing from a.to_h { array }:          0.991536   0.000049   0.991585 (  0.991623)
Accessing from b.to_h { array }:          0.999372   0.000037   0.999409 (  0.999476)
Accessing from a.map { function }.to_h:   0.988464   0.000073   0.988537 (  0.988588)
Accessing from b.map { function }.to_h:   1.000364   0.000066   1.000430 (  1.000472)
Accessing from a.map { array }.to_h:      0.988162   0.000042   0.988204 (  0.988280)
Accessing from b.map { array }.to_h:      0.997830   0.000049   0.997879 (  0.997946)
Accessing from Hash.new (with lookup)     1.003044   0.000068   1.003112 (  1.003149)
Accessing from a.each_with_object({})     1.006635   0.000000   1.006635 (  1.006668)
Accessing from b.each_with_object({})     0.993825   0.000000   0.993825 (  0.993867)
```

### Interpretation

So based on these results, you can say that there is a bill for memory allocation and garbage collection, which you can see in the rehearsal phase of [`Hash.new` (with lookup f(...))](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017612/4575793):  2.429415 s / 1.003149 s = 242% (or 1.42 s for building the structure). This means that a preconstructed data structure isn't even guaranteed to be faster than on-demand lookup, I expected the cost to be much higher. When heavily used it could still make sense to just use [Hash.new (with lookup f(...))](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017612/4575793). The consideration to make is when exactly the function is ran: on demand or previously constructed.
Imagine having a compute intensive task taking 10s

```
def f key
  sleep 10
  key
end
```

If you rarely need a result, just use `Hash.new` with a lookup function and bam - the declaration has virtually no runtime. Or you might have a strong focus on response time - then it's obv. better to have them up-front (like a dynamic-programming style lookup table). At around 16% deviation, the performance difference isn't huge, so you could also prefer code readability.    Starting with a plain array is mostly faster or equally fast so the format of your input data `a`/`b` made more of an impact here.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`each_with_object()` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
elem = [1,2,3,4]
h = elem.each_with_object({}) do |x, res|
  res[x] = x**2
end

puts h
```

The argument passed to `each_with_object({})` is the initial value of an intermediate object that is passed to the block as `res` variable. In each iteration we're adding new pair `key: value` to the `res` Hash and returning the Hash to be used in next iteration.

The method above pre-computes a very practical hash of squared values:

```
{1=>1, 2=>4, 3=>9, 4=>16}
```

Comment: My RuboCop tells me that `each_with_object` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017531/4575793) should be preferred.