# How do I create a hash where the keys are values from an array Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, key

I have an array:

```
arr = [a, ab, abc]
```

I want to make a hash, using the values of the array as the keys:

```
newhash = [a[1], ab[1], abc[1]]
```

I have tried:

```
arr.each do |r|
    newhash[r] == 1
end
```

to no avail.

How would I about accomplishing this in ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

== is comparison. = is assigning. So just modify == into =. It works.

```
newhash = {}
arr.each do |r|
  newhash[r] = 1
end
```

(I believe a, ab, abc are strings)

To learn more, this might help you. [Array to Hash Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028329/array-to-hash-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

If you are feeling like a one-liner, this will work as well

```
h = Hash[arr.collect { |v| [v, 1] } ]
```

`collect` is invoked once per element in the array, so it returns an array of 2-element arrays of key-value pairs.

Then this is fed to the hash constructor, which turns the array of pairs into a hash

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `#reduce` method from `Enumerable` (which is included into the `Array` class).

```
new_hash = arr.reduce({}) { |hsh, elem| hsh[elem] = 1; hsh }
```

And your `new_hash` looks like this in Ruby:

```
{"a": 1, "ab": 1, "abc": 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
ary = [[:foo, 1], [:bar, 2]]
Hash[ary] # => {:foo=>1, :bar=>2}
```

If you want to do it like you tried earlier, you want to initialize hash correctly:

```
ary = [:foo, :bar]
hash = {}
ary.each do |key|
  hash[key] = 1
end # => {:foo=>1, :bar=>2}
```